# Error using HttpClient to Post JSONObject

Tags: java, android, httpclient, json

The error I get is "StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork" using a

What I try to do here is to post all this data to the server using jsonobject. I really don't know what to do here since I'm using an activity and this class to manage all http requests.

This is my code:

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;  

public class HttpRequestManager {

String TAG = "Request Manager";

public String RegisterUser (String deviceId, String userNames, String userSurnames, String password,
                            String retypedPassword, String userIds,
                            String userCellphone, String userEmail) {



    //Log.i(TAG, deviceId);

    JSONObject registerFormObject = new JSONObject();

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/v1/registration");

    try {

        try {

            registerFormObject.put("device_id", deviceId);
            registerFormObject.put("device_type", "a");
            registerFormObject.put("names", userNames);
            registerFormObject.put("surnames", userSurnames);
            registerFormObject.put("cell", userCellphone);
            registerFormObject.put("email", userEmail);
            registerFormObject.put("password1", password);
            registerFormObject.put("password2", retypedPassword);
            registerFormObject.put("identification", userIds);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(registerFormObject.toString()));
        //httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    }


    return userSurnames;
} 


}
```

Any idea about how to solve this error?

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" done btw.

Comment: Android now forbids Network operations on the main thread. Try AsyncTask - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898370/android-threading-with-rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within an `Android` application you should avoid performing long running operations on the user interface `thread`. This includes file and network access.

`StrictMode` allows to setup policies in your application to avoid doing incorrect things. As of `Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)` **StrictMode** is configured to crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception, if network is accessed in the user interface thread.

While you should do network access in a background thread, this tutorial will avoid this to allow the user to learn network access independent from background processing.

If you are targeting `Android 3.0` or higher, you can turn this check off via the following code at the beginning of your onCreate() method of your activity.

see more here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html

about `AsyncTask` here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

```
public class RequesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                HttpRequestManager mHttpRequestManager new HttpRequestManager();
                String returnValue = mHttpRequestManager.RegisterUser()

                return returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                //your result here

        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

what @Machinarius said is correct. You can not execute Network activity on Main Thread. However to answer you question I have the solution for you.

You can create a new Class... Call it whatever you like (for purpose of this example lets assume it will be **RegUser**)and Inside that class... put this code. Of course change the Parameters **Register** function will take to yours.

```
public void Register(
                          // Parameters it takes IN
                            String deviceId, 
                            String userNames, 
                            String userSurnames, 
                            String password,
                            String retypedPassword, 
                            String userIds,
                            String userCellphone, 
                            String userEmail
                          )
        {
        //Start of the Code in Function

        //Create a JSON variable of type JSON
        JSONObject JSON = new JSONObject();


        //Get UnixTimeStamp (Used to get UniquePushMessageID)
        long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

        //Wrap all contacts and variabels to a single JSON object


    try {
                JSON.put("deviceId", deviceId);
                JSON.put("userNames", userNames);
                JSON.put("userSurnames", userSurnames);
                JSON.put("password", password);
...please add more yourself.
                JSON.put("contact", JSONcontacts); // Put JSON into JSON to create Array of Contacts
                JSON.put("channel", channel);
                JSON.put("unique", channel + String.valueOf(unixTime) ); //Create Unique MessageID (RSU-MAC+TimeInSec)
                JSON.put("icon", icon);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            Log.v("MAD", "About to send" + JSON.toString());

            //Send this JSON object to a server
            SendToServer(JSON.toString());
}
```

Now, in the same class please create a method called  **SendToServer**. As you can see, it uses Async Task :)

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public void SendToServer(final String JSON) {
        new AsyncTask() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                //Not Needed
            }

            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                //Create Array of Post Variabels
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                //Add a 1st Post Value called JSON with String value of JSON inside
                //This is first and last post value sent because server side will decode the JSON and get other vars from it.
                postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", String.valueOf(JSON)));

                //Declare and Initialize Http Clients and Http Posts
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL);

                //Format it to be sent
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                /* Send request and Get the Response Back */
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    //Log.v("MAD", "RESPONSE: " + responseBody + " | Length: " + String.valueOf(responseBody.length()));

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }// END of Send to Server
```

And this is it. Now in your MainActivity all you have to do is Declare RegUser:

```
RegUser registerUser = new RegUser();
```

And after all your TextFields where you enter the data... just a simple call:

```
registerUser.Register(username, password.. etc);
```

I hope this will solve your problem, it worked for me.